# How can I create graphs with label using PHP syntax?

Tags: php, graph

How can I create graphs with label using PHP syntax and integrate it with sql using phpmyadmin.

I just want to integrate my records to a graph to monitor the number of a specific number of records. I really don't know hot to get it from the records I've made in my phpmyadmin

Comment: Could you be more specific? what have you tried? what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @adrien I just want to integrate my records to a graph to monitor the number of a specific number of records. I really don't know hot to get it from the records I've made in my phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Open flash chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/)

You will be able to create flash charts using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Google Charts at https://developers.google.com/chart/. Easy to call from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use google charts. Its simple, effective and interactive too
visit : [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) 
i used it for my project.